# Building a model with a reactive formula in shiny using selected inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I have a problem with object 'input' not found in **formula**. When I try to use input of selectInput, it throws me this error. T tried everything, but nothing helps. Can someone help me with this issue please ?

**SERVER**

```
idk = reactive({
     id = sample(2, nrow(df1()), replace = TRUE, prob = c(input$slider, 1-input$slider))
     id
   })
   
   
   output$dev <- renderText({ 
     paste0("Training part is: ",input$slider) 
   })
   
   output$dev2 <- renderText({ 
     paste0("Testing part is: ",1-input$slider) 
   })
   
   train_datas = reactive({
     train_data = df1()[idk() == 1, ]
     train_data
   })
   
   test_datas = reactive({
     test_data = df1()[idk() == 2, ]
     test_data
   })

outVar = reactive({
     mydata = test_datas()
     names(mydata)
   })
   
   
   observe({
     updateSelectInput(session, "columns1",
                       choices = outVar()
     )})
   
   observe({
     updateSelectInput(session, "columns2",
                       choices = outVar()
     )})
   
   observe({
     updateSelectInput(session, "columns3",
                       choices = outVar()
     )})
   
   observe({
     updateSelectInput(session, "columns4",
                       choices = outVar()
     )})

   tree = reactive({
     mydata = train_datas()
     tree2 = ctree(formula = input$columns1 ~ input$columns2 + input$columns3 + input$columns4, data = mydata)
     tree2
   })
   
   output$try <- renderPrint({
     return(tree())
     
   })
```

**UI**

```
 tabPanel("Data prepare",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel( 
                          numericInput("slider", "Train data (0-1)", 1,
                                       0.1, 1, 0.05),
                          textOutput("dev"),
                          textOutput("dev2"),
                          tags$hr(),
                          textOutput("dev3"),
                          textOutput("dev4"),
                          tags$hr(),
                          selectInput('columns1', 'Columns1', ""),
                          selectInput('columns2', 'Columns2', ""),
                          selectInput('columns3', 'Columns3', ""),
                          selectInput('columns4', 'Columns4', "")
                         
                        ),
                        
                        mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("try"))
                    ))
```

I add whole code whichh is connect to my question. What I need is get input value of last four select inputs - column1, column2, column3, column4.

Comment: please provide the whole code for `ui` and `server` e.g. what is `test_datas`? Function or reactive value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to update choices of `selectInput` according to the current value of the available variables of the input data frame (`outVar` in your case).
Then, the selected choices will be used as response and predictor variables in a reactive model:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("response", "response", ""),
  selectInput("predictor", "predictor", ""),
  verbatimTextOutput("model")
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  # Example data
  data <- reactive(iris)

  variables <- reactive(colnames(data()))

  formula <- reactive({
    paste0(input$response, "~", input$predictor) %>% as.formula()
  })

  # dummy model using reactive formula
  model <- reactive({
    lm(formula = formula(), data = data())
  })

  # Display sth about the reactive model
  output$model <- renderText({
    model() %>%
      coefficients() %>%
      as.character()
  })

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = variables,
    handlerExpr = {
      updateSelectInput(session, "response", choices = variables(), selected = variables()[[1]])
      updateSelectInput(session, "predictor", choices = variables(), selected = variables()[[2]])
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but my problem is still same ... "object 'input' not found" in tree reactive which you can see in code

Comment: @Marquee I changed my minimal reproducible example. You need to create a reactive formula

Comment: Thanks maybe i should have said, that ctree is function which make decision tree and there is required :library(party)
library(e1071)
library(caret)

Comment: Since the issue is in the creation of the formula, we do not need the specific tree here. Try to make your example as minimal as possible so others do not need to install unnessesary packages

Comment: This is because there was no pre-selected choice at selectInput. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, but is there some reason why it works clearly with iris dataset but if I use train_datas it's not working ? When i use that, it is not load names of columns to selectInput, but if I use my older approach it works but then formula and model not working.

Comment: Do `variables <- reactive({ message("get new vars"); colnames(train_datas()))` to debug and see  if this is even called by the shiny event loop.

Comment: "Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6904
get new vars"

Comment: Good news: Seems that it was called.

Comment: It's not working also when I edit  data <- reactive(iris) to data <- reactive(test_datas())